# What do Hindu scriptures say about the shape of the Earth?

Tags: scripture, belief, science, earth

[misconception starts] Religious scriptures of other religions like Christianity say that the Earth is flat [misconception ends], however debunked by Science. But as it is a general belief of Hindu scriptures being more scientific, what do they say about the shape of the Earth ?

Comment: Yeah sure, I will take that into account from next time. New to this community. Apologies.

Comment: You can click on "That solved my problem" if you have found answer to your question  Also take a look at our [help] and [ask]  pages. It helps in understanding the site better.

Comment: sure @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I can't see the "That solved my problem" button (here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/DLjqkJI). Is it becuase others voted is at duplicate ? do i need to do anything now ?

Comment: Oh wasn't aware of that, new to stack exchange. Thanks @Akshay Kumar S

Comment: Can we be more respectful also I heard from Christain scholars world means different things so flat could be a land mass where the events of Christain mythos took place please be relevant to the question.